# Wordpress theme installation failed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, lampp

While Installing the WordPress theme, I get the error below

"
Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

Could not create directory. /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/universal-lite/

Theme installation failed.

"

Anyone please help me. I am stuck

Comment: Just put your theme inside '/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/' then activate from admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the user does not have sufficient permissions to create folders in this directory.

Try if you can create a folder in this directory yourself

```
$mkdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/test
```

If you want to grant **all** permissions for testing purposes to this directory and all sub-folders try

```
$sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities to failing theme upload.

1. Your folder dont have sufficient permission to create directory so first of all use this command to grant the access `chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/`
2. Or check whether your folder size is more than the upload limit? if it is, try to upload the theme using terminal or increase upload limit.